# Wordpress 6.3 headers already sent error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need to refresh my screen after curl has run but I get "headers already sent" error.

This is my code which is a plugin.

```
function fs_settings_admin_callback(){

    if ($_POST['generate']){
        $url = 'https://www.example.com/api/fs/v1/endpoint';
  
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

        $ret = curl_exec($curl);
        $result = json_decode($ret,true);
  
 
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
         // ob_end_clean() ;
          //ob_end_flush() ;
          //ob_flush();
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
}


function fs_add_submenu_page(){
    
    add_submenu_page(
         $parent_slug = 'edit.php?post_type=my_custom_post_type',
         $page_title = 'Settings', 
         $menu_title = 'Settings', 
         $capability = 'manage_options', 
         $menu_slug = 'fs_settings', 
         $callback = 'fs_settings_admin_callback', 
         $position = null 
    );    
}
```

I understand that probably I need to use output buffering but I cannot figure out how.  If I use ob_end_clean or others the screen will refresh but then is blank and would like to continue to see my form from initial submit.

Comment: How/when/where are you running that code? Is that inside of a hook? Are you making a remote request to a custom REST API endpoint?

Comment: I have added additional info to the original post to who how/when/where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not use output buffering, and instead, you just need to use the right hook to refresh the page — the one that you've used runs after the headers and content are already sent to the browser, hence it's not the right hook or that it should only be used to output the content for your custom admin menu page.

The hook that you should use is [`load-<page hook>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/), where `<page hook>` is the return value of [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) which is a hook suffix like `my_custom_post_type_page_fs_settings` in your case.

So for example:

- In the `fs_settings_admin_callback` function:

  ```php
  $hook_suffix = add_submenu_page(
      'edit.php?post_type=my_custom_post_type',
      your code here
  );

  add_action( "load-$hook_suffix", 'fs_settings_maybe_generate' );
  ```
- Then do the refresh in the callback specified above:

  ```php
  function fs_settings_maybe_generate() {
      if ( ! empty( $_POST['generate'] ) ) {
          // your code here

          header( 'Refresh: 0' );
          exit;
      }
  }
  ```

Another hook which you can use/try is [`admin_post_<action>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/) where `<action>` would be the value of a hidden input named `action` in your form. However, we won't be using the `Refresh` header, but instead, do a redirect to the form page.

- Sample form:

  ```php
  <form method="post" action="admin-post.php">
      <p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="generate" id="fs-generate" />
          <label for="fs-generate">Generate</label>
      </p>

      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="generate" />
      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'fs-generate' ); ?>

      <?php submit_button(); ?>
  </form>
  ```
- Now handle the form submissions:

  ```php
  add_action( 'admin_post_generate', 'fs_admin_post_generate' );
  function fs_admin_post_generate() {
      check_admin_referer( 'fs-generate' );

      if ( ! empty( $_POST['generate'] ) ) {
          // your code here
      }

      // Always redirect back.
      wp_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
      exit;
  }
  ```

<sub>See https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/ for details on adding an nonce field and other security measures.</sub>

Additionally, you should also utilize the WordPress's [HTTP API](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/making-http-requests/) for making HTTP/remote/external requests, e.g. [`wp_remote_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/):

```php
function fs_settings_maybe_generate() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['generate'] ) ) {
        $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://www.example.com/api/fs/v1/endpoint' );
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        // Do something with $body, if you want to.

        header( 'Refresh: 0' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seem that if I replace header("Refresh:0") with wp_redirect( wp_get_referer() ); it also works.  Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!